# How do i unsubscribe, leave, or delete himself from public group using facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have not found how I can leave a public group, using my application and api from facebook.

Is it possible to unsubscribe themselves and other members of the public group using facebook api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to unsubscribe from a group using the Graph API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/groups#delete